# Bootstrap 4 change icon in collapse

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I use bootstrap 4 alpha 6 version. In my page I have several collapse blocks. I want to change icon when user open/close that block. As I have several of these blocks I used class but it didnt work. Whats wrong I did? P.S. When I use id in JS works fine, but as you see I have several collapse block and dont want to "copy & paste".

**html:**

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
         <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
              <button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse-projects" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-projects">
                    <i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </button>
         </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-block">
        <div class="collapse" id="collapse-projects">
           ***SOME CONTENT***
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
         <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
              <button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse-tasks" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-tasks">
                    <i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </button>
         </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-block">
        <div class="collapse" id="collapse-tasks">
           ***SOME CONTENT***
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('.collapse')
                .on('shown.bs.collapse', function() {
                    $(this)
                        .parent()
                        .find(".fa-eye")
                        .removeClass("fa-eye")
                        .addClass("fa-eye-slash");
                })
                .on('hidden.bs.collapse', function() {
                    $(this)
                        .parent()
                        .find(".fa-eye-slash")
                        .removeClass("fa-eye-slash")
                        .addClass("fa-eye");
                });
        });
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is: all your `button` and `.collapse` elements are in the same DOM level, which means when `.collapse`'s `shown.bs.collapse` or `hidden.bs.collapse` event is fired, the `$(this).parent()` in the event handler point to `.collapse`'s parent -- the most outside one that is not displayed in your code. Let's make it as `OUTER`. Then, when you invoke `find`, `removeClass` and `addClass` on `OUTER`, all icons will be changed, which is why "it didn't work".

To fix this issue, you need to make a unit wrapper which contains a group of `button` and `.collapse` elements. In this way, `$(this).parent()` will point to the group and only the clicked button icon is changed.

I've made a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cshao/b9cvx0rh/3/) for the fix, please check.

Comment: It works fine in your example but when I tried it in my project it didnt works.  I used it in different DOM level. I update my code in post. Can you check it?

Comment: @NurzhanNogerbek your code snippet works well, please check https://jsfiddle.net/cshao/j6xsrucm/1/ I just copy&paste your html and js. Please note Bootstrap CSS and JS, FontAwesome JS should be imported.

Comment: Well I didn't show some parts because I thought they are not important (card-header, card-block, d-flex), but now when I checked the code in jsfiddle.net it does not work. Look my post again pls. Its full code. Do you have any ideas now?

Comment: @NurzhanNogerbek your html structure is not correct. For your `.collapse`, its `.parent()` does not have any `.fa-eye` or `.fa-eye-slash` descendant, that's why the icon is never changed. To fix this issue, you need to use `.parent().parent()`, please check https://jsfiddle.net/cshao/j6xsrucm/3/